# How to sum up all the arrays (identical sizes) inside a cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sum, cell, cell-array

For instance, I have the following cell array:

```
a = [1,2,3; 1,5,8; 6,5,0; 0,0,2];
A = cell(3,4);
for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:4
        A{i,j} = (j-i)*a;
    end
end
```

How could I sum up all the elements i.e. `A{1,1} + A{1,2} + ... + A{3,4}`?

Answer (score 8):

[Concatenate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) the matrices in each cell along the third dimension and then [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) along the third dimension.

```
TD = cat(3, A{:});    %Converting the cell array to a 3D array
result = sum(TD, 3);  %Summation of 3D slices
```